# Corrupt ext4 filesystem after e2image interrupted

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, corruption, system-recovery

I have a ~450 gigabyte ext4 filesystem, located at `/dev/sda5` on my computer. The partition it resided in, however, was about a gigabyte bigger. So I used the command `e2image -ra -p -O XXXX` to move the filesystem to the left, so I could use the extra gigabyte on a partition at `/dev/sda6`. I didn't run that exact command, of course, I forget the decimal value after -O (I didn't run these commands manually, this was done by GParted). `e2image` got forcefully killed (signal nine) about 100/170 gigabytes through the process. I mounted `sda5` read-only, and got many errors about invalid inodes and bad structure files when I tried to access various files or list various directories. So I ran `fsck` (which I now realize probably damaged things further), and directories like `/home` and `/run` (which probably the contained the most data on the whole partition), which I wasn't able to run `ls` in succesfully, and got lots of error messages about, were non-existent. I ran `grep` on `sda5`, and found various files in `/home` still intact, but I couldn't access them normally because `/home` was deleted by `fsck`. How can I recover files without manually searching for them with `grep`, `less`, or a hex editor? I have very important files I need to get back.

Comment: Please list the the exact commands you ran, "moving a partition" doesn't really tell much what has been done here. Also, the [ext4 mailinglists](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mailinglists) may be useful too.

Comment: @ckujau I do not remember what command GParted used.

Comment: @ckujau Something like `e2image -ra -p -O 123456 /dev/sda5`

Comment: You have comprehensively destroyed your filesystem. For future reference, you might like to take away a couple of lessons: always take a backup before performing major surgery on a filesystem, and don't use `SIGKILL` needlessly. :(

Comment: You can try looking for them using `debugfs`, which allows you to access files by their inodes, then relink them to another location. I had a similar problem not too long ago.

Comment: Whatever recovery steps you try, please *first* make an image (copy) of the entire disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the commenters are right that your file system is pretty well broken.  I once accidentally wrote /dev/zero to my main hard drive (while operating) for about half a second before killing it.  I was able to use Photorec (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover my partition table (pretty much automagically) and I am still using that system.

I think you should take a look at Photorec, since it is open-source (yeah!), and because it reads directly from the disk (ignoring the filesystem), so I suspect it might easily save you many hours of searching for files manually.

**Also, The commenter who says image your current, messed-up hard drive right now is definitely correct**